# Is there a way to access Nokogiri::XML::Attr by using a symbol key, not a string key

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have a code like this

```
require 'nokogiri'
url = ENV['URL']
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
link = doc.css('a#foo').attr('href').value
```

I want to access to `Nokogiri::XML::Attr` by using symbol like this.

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url), hash_key_symbol: true)
link = doc.css('a#foo').attr(:href).value
```

I couldn't find information for it, but maybe I've overlooked it.
Is there a option like this?

Comment: What about just using `Symbol#to_s`?

Comment: it's more irksome for me to write `'href'`, thanks anyway.

Comment: Have you tried using a symbol?

Comment: yes, and it failed with `TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into String`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling [`attr`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet#attr-instance_method) on the [`NodeSet`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet) returned from [`css`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Searchable#css-instance_method), not on a single [`Node`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node) object. [`attr` on a `Node`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node#%5B%5D-instance_method) will accept a symbol to specify the attribute, and [has done for a while](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/commit/6ac0e37db1d4edee1cd45c1ae2b639c7cad8c4a9), but it looks like the corresponding change hasn’t been made to `NodeSet#attr`. Note that the `NodeSet` version of `attr` is for setting the attribute on all nodes in the set, and will only return the value of the attribute on the *first* node it contains if you don’t specify a value.

You can use [`at_css`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Searchable#at_css-instance_method) to explicitly only select the first matching node of your query, then you can use a symbol:

```
doc.at_css('a#foo').attr(:href).value
```

Alternatively you could select the node from the node set by its index:

```
doc.css('a#foo')[0].attr(:href).value
```

Comment: Thanks! Just a small fix, when I use symbol I didn't need to use `value` method. `doc.at_css('a#foo').attr(:href)` returns string value.

Answer (score 1):

The simple way to access a parameter in a tag is to use the "hash" `[]` syntax:

```
require 'nokogiri'

html = <<EOT
<html>
  <body>
    <a href="blah" id="foo">bar</a>
  </body>
</html>
EOT

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
doc.at('a#foo')['href'] # => "blah"
```

But we can use a symbol:

```
doc.at('a#foo')[:href] # => "blah"
```

Note, `at` is equivalent to `search('a#foo').first`, and both return a Node. `search`, and its CSS and XPath variants return NodeSets, which don't have the ability to return the attribute of a specific node or all nodes. To process multiple nodes use `map`:

```
html = <<EOT
<html>
  <body>
    <a href="blah" class="foo">bar1</a>
    <a href="more_blah" class="foo">bar2</a>
  </body>
</html>
EOT

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
doc.search('a.foo').map{ |n| n['href'] } # => ["blah", "more_blah"]
```